# Youtube UMG content restricted when embedded into HTTPS page. Not restricted embedded in HTTP

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, https, youtube-api

As the title says. 
If i embed a youtube video with this exact same code on the same site on 2 different cpanel servers - running equivalent PHP and apache. Difference is - One is SSL, one port80 HTTP.

Both UK servers.

HTTP will play, SSL site will give UMG error for restricted content.

An example of the embed generated HTML is

`<iframe id="ytplayer" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"      src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/My0HQ0QkGLQ?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.co.uk" type="text/html">`

Php page is called with the URI browse.php?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyAyuZPNo2w&type=video Then stripvid() gets the embed ID.

Is there any way to load a page as HTTP inside a HTTPS frame? Both pages on the same domain.

UPDATE:: Okay so redirecting the video URL to a non-HTTP server to parse and return an iframe works. but thats HTTPS page -> HTTP iframe -> Youtube iframe .
There will be techies here who will go nuts at that amount of iframes... ah well. Come up with something better? ;)

Changing '&origin=https://example.com"' to http doesn't help.

```
    else if($_GET['type']=="video"){

$yurl = stripvid($url);
if  ($yurl!=$url){
echo '<link href="examplecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.animate-colors.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="pixeljs.php"></script></head><body onload="sizewindow()"><div id="ytplayerdiv" style="height:100%; width:100%">

<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" style="height:100%; width:100%"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$yurl.'?autoplay=1&origin=https://example.com"
frameborder="0"/>

</div>

</body></html>';
}
```

Comment: would file_get_contents or Curl help to do fake headers maybe?

Comment: what if u put the iframe in an iframe whose source is your http site?

Comment: That would be okay but i'd be using 2 servers for one job. My HTTP server is just a dev box. not really a live environment.